# Publish NPM package with only non-bundled dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

Lets say we're developing a small javascript library **L**.

The code is in ES6. To use some utility function, like `debounce`, we install lodash as a dependency.

At build the webpack transpiles the code, bundling the *tree shaked* lodash code, and we end up with a nice little javascript file we want to publish and share as a npm package.

Now, the `package.json` file lists lodash as a dependency. But that is only true at build time, it is not really needed in production.

What's the proper way to handle this kind of situation?
Does it make sense to consider lodash a devDependency? As such, only webpack's `externals` would be "real" dependencies?

Or should we somehow tamper the `package.json` file before publishing it?

Do you know any real examples of projects handling this question?

Answer (score 4):

Webpack "merges" the code of the project with that of the used code of the non-external *dependencies* into some `bundle.js` file. This file is then published to NPM, along with a `package.json` file, which lists all of the dependencies, independently of these being external or embedded.

All of the code of packages referenced in `dependencies` (or `optionalDependencies`, or `peerDependencies`) is expected to be "production" code.
While code in `devDependencies` is expected to be used only at "development" time, and is thus "development" code. Under this principle, I believe that it would be incorrect to declare non-external dependencies as development dependencies.

However, if all dependencies, embedded or external, are declared equally in the published `package.json` file, there is no way for a runtime environment to know which are the real dependencies that need to be made available to the package — the ones that the package will *import* at runtime and which better be available.

For the Node.js environment, bundles and Webpack are not normally used, so this never came to be an issue — all dependencies are always installed (never merged/bundled).

However, if you use the `package.json` file to drive some web-packages runtime environment, the way that *dependencies* are currently included in published `package.json` is not suitable.

You might want to take a look at [Pika Web's](https://github.com/pikapkg/web#packagejson-config) `devDependencies` `package.json` property, which aims to solve a comparable problem (even though their mojo is "a future without Webpack"). They also introduce the concept of publishing a different `package.json` file than that which is checked-in (tampering the `package.json` before publishing, as you say).

Interestingly, it looks like a related tool, Pika Pack, caught the attention of NPM folks and is being considered to [become part of NPM](https://github.com/pikapkg/pack/issues/34). So, *maybe*, NPM has become aware of the specific package format needs of web projects' workflows.